# VS Code refuses to connect to server via Remote SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can not connect to my server with "Remote SSH" on VSCode.
When I enter the password, It asks again, then again and then it terminates the connection.
But I have entered the correct password.

Can anybody help me?

I tried to connect multiple times and even changing the FTP access password on the "plesk" server page.